# Como popular uma propriedade do parâmetro com acesso GET

Tags: c#, método, parâmetros

Para entender o que quero fazer, observem o parâmetro FormClosing() do WindowsForms:

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     var r = e.CloseReason;
 }
```

Analisando esse método, eu não consigo modificar a propriedade CloseReason dentro do método, apenas receber. Mas como essa propriedade é populada por valores, sendo que o seu acesso é GET? Como funciona esse método internamente?

Estou tentando copiar o mesmo raciocínio do método acima, mas não estou conseguindo. A forma que estou fazendo abaixo, está dando erro.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Modify modify = new Modify();
        modify.Refresh += Modify_Refresh;
        modify.Start();
    }

    // esse é o método que está seguindo a mesma linha de raciocínio do método acima
    private void Modify_Refresh(ValueArgs e)
    {
        var r = e.IsRunning;
    }
}

public class Modify
{
    public delegate void EventRefresh(ValueArgs e);
    public event EventRefresh Refresh;
    public void Start()
    {
        ValueArgs valueArgs = new ValueArgs();
        valueArgs.IsRunning = true;
        Refresh(valueArgs);
    }
}

public class ValueArgs
{
    public bool IsRunning { get; }
}
```

Observem que quando vou setar IsRunning para TRUE, dá erro dizendo que a propriedade não é atribuível, mas apenas leitura. Como faço esse código funcionar da maneira correta, seguindo a mesma linha de raciocínio do método FormClosing() do Windows Form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (...) sendo que o seu acesso é GET? Como funciona esse método internamente?

Em vez de declarar a propriedade na forma "auto-implementada", implemente-a usando um campo privado(*backing field*).

Ao contrário da propriedade "auto-implementada", que usa um *blacking field* implicito, a forma tradicional, *blacking field* explicito, permite que esta  seja "setada" sem a necessidade de declarar um *set* para a propriedade.

Essa é a forma como a classe [FormClosingEventArgs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FormClosingEvent.cs.html#https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FormClosingEvent.cs.html,https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FormClosingEvent.cs.html,https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FormClosingEvent.cs.html,d2a836f44661011a,references) implementa a propriedade `CloseReason`. É usado um campo privado(*backing field*) onde é guardado o CloseReason que é passado ao construtor de FormClosingEventArgs.
A implementação do `get`, da propriedade, retorna o valor do *backing field*.

```
public class FormClosingEventArgs : CancelEventArgs {
    private CloseReason closeReason;

    public FormClosingEventArgs(CloseReason closeReason, bool cancel)
    : base(cancel) {
        this.closeReason = closeReason;                                           
    }

    public CloseReason CloseReason {
        get {
            return closeReason;
        }
    }
}
```

Aplicando ao código da pergunta seria algo assim:

```
public class Modify
{
    public delegate void EventRefresh(ValueArgs e);
    public event EventRefresh Refresh;
    public void Start()
    {
        ValueArgs valueArgs = new ValueArgs(true);
        Refresh(valueArgs);
    }
}

public class ValueArgs
{
    private isRunning;

    public ValueArgs(bool isRunning)
    {
        this.isRunning = isRunning;
    }

    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get
        {
            return isRunning;
        }
    }
}
```

Uma outra forma é criar as classes Modify e ValueArgs em outro *assembly* e declarar como `internal` o *set* da propriedade `IsRunning`:

```
public class ValueArgs
{
    public bool IsRunning { get; internal set;}
}
```

Sendo o *set* `internal`, e estando a classe Modify no mesmo *assembly*, ele está acessível para ela.